# how to draw multiple bar plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have this array to create a multiple bar plot,

```
[
    ['n', 1, 2556], 
    ['n', 2, 21484], 
    ['n', 3, 11488], 
    ['o', 1, 602], 
    ['o', 2, 4708], 
    ['o', 3, 3006], 
    ['t', 1, 21966], 
    ['t', 2, 122067], 
    ['t', 3, 72724]
]
```

this is what i'm expecting to draw,

[image]

Now how do i do this with `matplotlib` ?, i've tried few things they didnt work

Comment: Matplotlib has a [grouped bar chart demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py). What exactly was the problem implementing this method? You might also benefit from creating a pandas dataframe from this list of lists - [pandas simplifies routine plotting tasks](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html).

Comment: @Mr.T i just need to transform this 3d array into a box plot like above